# Shared Element Transition Between Fragment in Viewpager containing recyclerview to a new Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-transitions

I have an activity that has a viewpager containing 2 fragments managed by a tab adapter. Basically an activity with 2 tabs. In one of these fragments, I have a recyclerview that shows a list of items I can scroll through. What I want to do, is when I click on one of these items, to have a shared element transition into a new fragment or activity that has a detailed view of the item. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you [read the documentation on fragment shared element transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate#shared)?